# Aws ALB Health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services

HI I have created 2 ec2 and they are under an ALB, ALB is doing health checks at a custom location i.e /var/www/html/web/health.html.

I have index.html at /var/www/html.

So now the question is why do my ALB keep showing index.html even if both of my host become unhealthy(i removed the health file from /var/www/html/web/ location).

Comment: is it still happening?

Comment: yes it is still happening

Comment: can you send the alb url?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. There are two important scenarios:

- ALB looks only at the HTTP response returned by a health check endpoints. As long as an endpoint returns 200 ALB will treat it as healthy.
- If there are no healthy targets, ALB will forward the requests to, e.g.,  all the instances in a target group.  Or more precisely, from the docs: "If no Availability Zone contains a healthy target, the load balancer nodes route requests to all targets."